# Use Dotnetnuke authentication for a FTP server

Tags: asp.net, ftp, authorization, dotnetnuke

We have to put up a new FTP server (FTP on SSL) but want the users to login to it using their username and password from the asp.net website which is on Dotnetnuke. Our website is running on windows 2003 R2. Any idea on how we can acheive this? I looked into CompleteFTP, which might be a solution with a cost. Are there any free FTP servers that provide this out the box or with little bit of coding? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FileZila Server](http://filezilla-project.org/) which is a free FTP server.

-- Edited Answer based on comment --

FTP in IIS7+ supports sql server authentication. 
Reference: http://forums.iis.net/t/1146472.aspx/1

Here is the walkthrough: http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-the-ftp-service/configuring-ftp-with-net-membership-authentication-in-iis-7

But I see you are running windows server 2003 R2, so you need to [upgrade to IIS7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff633422%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to use this facility.

Comment: But how do I authenticate users using asp.net website's authentication? I don't want to creates users in FileZilla manually, I want to use usernames and passwords from the asp.net website.

Comment: I have updated the answer. FileZilla server doesnt support sql server, but IIS7 does.

Comment: I don't have any control over the OS. As far as I searched IIS7 is not supported in windows 2003. So, what options I have for windows 2003?

Comment: In that case you dont have much options. You have to use FileZilla and manually maintain the users or go for the paid software.

Comment: Is microsfot FTP server a free server? Can it be made to accessable for external users? I didn't find anything about using it as non-personal use.

Comment: Yes thats correct. It is free and you can manage FTP server through windows authentication.

Comment: I read the links you have sent for setting up FTP with IIS7.0. I am confused, it looks like I am setting up ftp where my website resides. Right now my set up in IIS is my working website (wchich runs on dotnetnuke) is set as default website. But I don't want users to add the files to my website, I want to set up a different folder for ftp but use user login information from by website. Could you please clarify how I can do that?

Comment: The link is for IIS7. I think that's why you are confused.

Answer (score 0):

[CompleteFTP](https://enterprisedt.com/products/completeftp/) now has a [Free Edition](https://enterprisedt.com/products/completeftp/free/), which has a feature set that's similar to that of FileZilla Server (FTP/FTPS, unlimited users, virtual file-system).  Its configuration is in a SQL Server Compact database, so you should be able to integrate with it fairly easy by querying that database's User table for user-names and password hashes.